# MvvmCross SQLite composite key

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to learn how to support composite primary keys in MvvmCross using the MvvmCross Community SQLite Plugin.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626535/186046) it has been supported since at least Oct 2014. Does anyone know how to do this?

If I implement a model class with two [PrimaryKey] attributes then the call to CreateTable will throw a SQLite exception.

There doesn't appear to be a CompositeKey attribute.

- My Core PCL project references Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite via NuGet.
- My Droid project references Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite & Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.Droid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is supported if you download the latest source and compile.  The NuGet package for the newest version hasn't been released yet.

Be aware that you need at least version 3.5 of MvvmCross.