# Sqlite.Net-PCL composite primary key

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'd like to use composite primary key in many-to-many table relationship. The obj class to create table is:

```
    [Table("relationsip_tab")]
class HtmlSrcFileRelationship {

    [Column("src_fk"),PrimaryKey]
    public string srcFk { get; set; }

    [Column("file_fk"), PrimaryKey]
    public string fileFk { get; set; }
}
```

It gave me an error `EXCEPTION: SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: table "relationsip_tab" has more than one primary key`

I am using *Sqlite for Universal Windows Platform*,*SQLite.Net-PCL* and *System.Data.SQLite* as references. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Looks like composite keys are not natively supported. Though there appears to be some workarounds. I found the following link that describes it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26623146/how-to-use-sqlite-net-extensions-with-composite-keys